# C# RSA implementation - encrypt and decrypt string

Tags: c#, string, encryption, rsa, implementation

I need to implement simple RSA program in C# which will encrypt and decrypt strings (I've only found working example with integers not strings). Here's what I have:

```
public static BigInteger euklides(BigInteger e, BigInteger phi)
    {

        BigInteger x = BigInteger.Zero;
        BigInteger y = BigInteger.One;
        BigInteger lastx = BigInteger.One;
        BigInteger lasty = BigInteger.Zero;
        BigInteger temp;
        BigInteger phiOriginal = phi;

        while (!phi.Equals(BigInteger.Zero))
        {
            BigInteger q = BigInteger.Divide(e, phi);
            BigInteger r = e % phi;

            e = phi;
            phi = r;

            temp = x;
            x = BigInteger.Subtract(lastx, BigInteger.Multiply(q, x));
            lastx = temp;

            temp = y;
            y = BigInteger.Subtract(lasty, BigInteger.Multiply(q, y)); 
            lasty = temp;
        }
        if (lastx.CompareTo(BigInteger.Zero) > 0)
            return lastx;
        else
            return BigInteger.Subtract(phiOriginal, BigInteger.Negate(lastx));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string p = "7980724731397402975742029729905308770673214017611336839039040369204140805514764089662732987804985392082433047940750616286743290036112256089536100737587703";
        string q = "11740715087896814955393784459915361965809210593358905908497824655235476226804879681331854108325808626683143689269719764318983014066100961329905775841321093";

        //Convert string to BigInteger
        BigInteger rsa_p = BigInteger.Parse(p);
        BigInteger rsa_q = BigInteger.Parse(q);

        BigInteger rsa_n = BigInteger.Multiply(rsa_p, rsa_q);

        BigInteger rsa_fn = BigInteger.Multiply((rsa_p - 1), (rsa_q - 1));

        BigInteger rsa_e = 13;

        BigInteger rsa_d = euklides(rsa_e, rsa_fn);


        string message = "hellojs";
        byte[] buffer2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger(buffer2);
        BigInteger C = BigInteger.ModPow(m, rsa_e, rsa_n);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted: " + Convert.ToBase64String(C.ToByteArray()));

        BigInteger M = BigInteger.ModPow(C, rsa_d, rsa_n);

        byte[] decoded2 = M.ToByteArray();

        if (decoded2[0] == 0)
        {
            decoded2 = decoded2.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray();
        }
        string message3 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded2);


        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + message3);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My problem is decrypting - I get some random unreadable characters. It seems something is wrong with converting string to BigInteger before encryption and BigInteger to string after decryption. Do anyone have any idea how to fix it? Thanks :)

EDIT:

For values which were hardcoded, program didn't work. But for another values like:
p 8954937300280438804244939471563100247837695704192373673128222819901439388583431335500737707702230367892764837438054304217178172911151362857419350093873829

q 11326960495280396859963951277476202902476795535605385467047045654941363025487995731611833231534039530362375614741751500907989679189162164468639573092827123

it's working now. I have no idea why :)

Comment: did you check that the string -> big integer -> string round trip actuall works without the encrypt decrypt

Comment: BTW the 'normal' way to encrypt data with RSA is to use RSA once to encrypt and share a symmetric key  and to use the symmetric key for the actual payload encryption.

Comment: yea, I know that, but it has to be as simple as it can be.
string to BigInteger to string works actually without encryption and decryption. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unrelated but you can make your code much cleaner by taking advantage of the overloaded operators with BigInteger. E.G. "if(lastx.CompareTo(BigInteger.Zero) > 0)" becomes "if(lastx > 0)"